# soap/JMS Tibco integration?

Tags: apache-axis, tibco-ems

Does any body have any sample,examples blogs..set instruction for soap/jms integration with tibco EMS

I have successfully tested soap/jms with Active MQ, but with the same setup instructions,not able to integrate with tibco EMS.

Although the Axis2 is connected to Tibco with initializing message ,the deployed soap wsdl based queue does not appear in the Tibco EMS by default.

Have already googled /yahooed  last 3 days.... but no success

with regards
Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok After 3 days of Slogging found the answer

Quickway for Queue ( similar for Topic )

1)Login to Tibco EMS Server , Create a user/passwd and grant full privileges of Queue or Topic.

2)Create a Queue as ( same name as that of Soap services as seen in the Services screen of Axis2 ) on Tibco EMS with and the user should have grant access over the created Queue.

3)Create another Temp Queue by any other name with similar privileges to the user [ this queue would be used to listen to the response of the Soap message set into the 1st Queue ].

4) Remove tags /Version.aar from Axis2 setup or additional Queues need for Version also need to be created on Tibco EMS-JMS

5)On Axis2 server in axis2.xml search for "transportReceiver & transportSender add the tags as defined below

```
<transportReceiver name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener">
<parameter name="tibQueueConnectionFactory">    
<parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory</parameter>    
<parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">tcp://<IP of JMS SERVER>:<PORT of JMS SERVER></parameter> 
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
<parameter locked="false" name="transport.jms.UserName"><userid as per JMS Queue proivelages></parameter>
<parameter locked="false" name="transport.jms.Password"><password as per JMS Queue privelages></parameter>
<parameter locked="false" name="transport.jms.CacheLevel">session</parameter>   
</parameter>
<parameter name="default">
<parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory</parameter>
<parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">tcp://<IP of JMS SERVER>:<PORT of JMS SERVER></parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
<parameter locked="false" name="transport.jms.UserName"><userid as per JMS Queue proivelages></parameter>
<parameter locked="false" name="transport.jms.Password"><password as per JMS Queue privelages></parameter>
<parameter locked="false" name="transport.jms.CacheLevel">session</parameter>
</parameter>
</transportReceiver> 

<transportSender name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender"/>
```

Restart Tibco Server ,then Axis2 (standalone/Tomcat)

Download & Use "Tibco UI - Gems ,connect to Tibco EMS , Open the Axis2 designated Queue and set the Replyto to the Temp Queue and fire the Soap XML, and watch the magic.

If u do not have Gems, then write up a Java code to Produce messages on to the Axis2 designated Queue ,set the Replyto to the TempQueue.  Fire the Soap XML and validate the answer in the temp Queue.

with regards
karthik